# JQuery .slideDown doesn't animate on tr:last-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to animate a table row that I append as 'display: none' to an existing table using .slideDown. The new tr appears but it doesn't do any animation.
FadeIn works perfectly instead.
I don't know what to do and I'd like to use that particular animation.

Here's the code and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p97ekp7g/1/

HTML

```
<div id="timesSection">
    <table id="tableTimes">
        <tr>
            <th class="number0">#</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>P</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="number1">1</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>91</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Js

```
function insertAfterLastChild() {
    var i = 0;

    // search for last row
    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function () {
        var n = $(this).text();
        if (n > i) {
            i = n
        }
    });
    i++; // increase index to add code in a new row
    var stringClassNumber = 'number' + i;
    var string = '<tr style="display: none"><td class="' + stringClassNumber + '">' + i + '</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr>';

    $(string).appendTo($('#tableTimes tbody'));
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#tableTimes tbody tr:last-child').slideDown(1000);
    }, 1000)
}

insertAfterLastChild();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Side animations do not work on `tr`.  You can add divs inside each td and slide them, but the tr will not animate this way directly.